# match "#" followed by numbers" using regular expressions php

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this in a string. And need to get "USING REGULAR EXPRESSIONS" not explode not substr.. the words that follows "#123" or "#345345" the numbers vary in lenght.

```
String = "address number between #258 Kentucky";
```

In that case get Kentucky. I have used this but doesn't work.

```
\b#([0-9]+)\b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `\b` (word boundary) before `#` which is a non-word character.

Just use this regex:

```
#([0-9]+)\s+(\w+)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT1sI1/6)